# vscode.dev with a web extension selected via URL

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to start a vscode.dev session with a extensions pre-selected via URL?

The official Blogpost just states this possibility for color themes and specific extensions. See here https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/10/20/vscode-dev#_speaking-of-urls

Is it possible to do this with any extension or combination of extensions?
I also didn't find anything in the Backlog for that.

Comment: Are you opening a repo? If so, you could put a vscode suggested extensions list

Comment: My goal is to share a link to my extension, that directly opens in vscode.dev. Just like i can share a link to this color theme: https://vscode.dev/theme/sdras.night-owl
Thanks for the idea of a workaround.

Comment: I’d just share the link to the extension marketplace page

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, in the announcement video [on YouTube](https://youtu.be/hdNipVZK53A), I haven't seen anything about it.

## But is it a hidden thing then?

**No.** I see (at least) when using https://vscode.dev/?extensions=esbenp.prettier-vscode (using **Prettier** as an example) it will not install Prettier.